# RegExp in Javascript to allow partial string matching of 'Manchester' but not match 'Manchester Road'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to search for 'Manchester' the city in my web form, which searches my mongoDB. I dont want streets or roads or anything that contains Manchester like e.g. 'Godmanchester'. I just want the city/string 'Manchester' or partial like 'Manchest' or 'Mancheste' so that i can catch typos.
Before I started I was getting answers like 'Godmanchester' and 'Manchester Road' as well as the correct 'Manchester'.
I managed to get rid of the 'Godmanchester' matches by using the '^' in my RegExp.
Then I managed to get rid of 'Manchester Road' by using this RegExp statement:

```
new RegExp('^(?!Manchester Road|Manchester Old Road)' + req.query.search, 'i') :
```

The problem now is, I'd have to explicitly state each word/phrase that I don't want (e.g. 'Manchester Road', 'Leeds Road', 'Liverpool Road' etc). This would be a massive array, not good.
I really need a javascript RegExp that just removed anything with the word 'road' in it. So I tried this:

```
new RegExp('^((?!road).)*$' + req.query.search, 'i') :
```

But it returns zero results in my javascript. However, if use

```
/^((?!road).)*$/i
```

in a Regex tester tool like https://regex101.com/ it works fine. So could be the way I'm writing it into my javascript...

Comment: `^((?!road).)*$` matches a *whole string* that does not contain `road`. When adding something on the right, the regex will never match anything since `$` is end of string.

Comment: I think you want `^(?!.*Manchester\s+Road).*Manchester`, or, with word boundaries, ``^(?!.*\bManchester\s+Road\b).*\bManchester\b``, something like `new RegExp('^(?!.*' + 
req.query.search +'\\s+Road).*' + req.query.search, 'i')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for helping. I added ```new RegExp('^(?!.*' +  req.query.search +'\\s+Road).*' + req.query.search, 'i')``` but my server.js failed with 'undefined' as the error. I should have shown more of my code probably. Here it is working at present, before any changes: ```const test = (req.query.search) ?
    new RegExp('^(?!Manchester Road|Manchester Old Road)' + req.query.search, 'i') :
    undefined```

Comment: I think it should not look like that, why set a RegExp object to undefined deliberately? You need to use a different logic.

Comment: Sounds like an NLP task more than a regex task... What if the user writes `"Manchester Rd."`? OK, add that to the regex too... throw in all the possible typo catches and a million edge cases later you still have things it'll miss...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, I managed to get it working with your suggestion to use ```new RegExp('^(?!.*' +  req.query.search +'\\s+Road).*' + req.query.search, 'i')```   Would you know how i add to this to also filter out 'Old Road' as well as 'Road' please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dynamically built regex like

```
new RegExp('^(?!.*\\b' +  req.query.search +'(?:\\s+Old)?\\s+Road\\b).*\\b' + req.query.search + '\\b', 'i')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ885P/1/)

The regex is

```
^(?!.*\bManchester(?:\s+Old)?\s+Road\b).*\bManchester\b
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*\bManchester(?:\s+Old)?\s+Road\b)` - fail the match if there is `Manchester` as a whole word, then an optional 1+ whitespaces and `Old`, and then 1+ whitespaces and `Road` as a whole word
- `.*\bManchester\b` - any text followed with `Manchester` as a whole word.